# How to join strings in a table in kdb?

Tags: kdb

I would like to join string in kdb but didn't work well. This is the data:

```
tab:([]service:`CS`CS.US`CS.US_ABC;y:1 2 3)


`CS 1
`CS.US  2
`CS.US_ABC  3
```

I would like to add :0 and :primary depending on the given parameter. 0 is working now

```
update service:`$(((string[service],'(":"))),'("C"$string 0)) from tab
```

If I would like the data to become

```
`CS:primary 1
`CS.US:primary  2
`CS.US_ABC:primary  3
```

and the primary is either string or symbol, how could I join?

I am parameterizing the 0 and primary.

Currently, 0 works as follows

```
update service:`$(((string[service],'(":"))),'( "0")) from tab
```

but "primary" is not working

```
update service:`$(((string[service],'(":"))),'( "primary")) from tab
```

Comment: It looks like you're writing your titles stylistically in all lower-case. Please don't do that - as this is spotted by editors, it may be repaired, so if you can write them in sentence case, you'll be saving some volunteers some work. The personal pronoun "I" is always upper case, as are proper nouns such as Python or Windows.

Comment: Also, if you could refrain from signing posts, that would be good too - they are also generally discouraged. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want primary to be a parameter rather than a fixed string, the following will work (primary is "no" in this example):

```
q)update {`$string[y],\:":",x}[primary;]service from tab
service      y
--------------
CS:no        1
CS.US:no     2
CS.US_ABC:no 3
```

If primary is a fixed string then you can place it inside the lambda in lieu of "x" and replace "y" with "x", yielding the following:

```
q)update {`$string[x],\:":","primary"}service from tab
service           y
-------------------
CS:primary        1
CS.US:primary     2
CS.US_ABC:primary 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query gives you a length error:

```
q)tab:([]service:`CS`CS.US`CS.US_ABC;y:1 2 3)
q)update service:`$(((string[service],'(":"))),'( "primary")) from tab
'length
  [0]  update service:`$(((string[service],'(":"))),'( "primary")) from tab
                                                    ^
```

This happens because `,'` (concatenate each) expects vectors of equal length on both sides, but gets a table column size (3) vector on the left and a character vector of length 7 on the right. Notice what happens when you pass 3 characters:

```
q)update service:`$(((string[service],'(":"))),'( "pri")) from tab
service     y
-------------
CS:p        1
CS.US:r     2
CS.US_ABC:i 3
```

Each row gets a different suffix.  What you want is to use `,\:` (concatenate each-left):

```
q)update service:`$(((string[service],'(":"))),\:( "primary")) from tab
service           y
-------------------
CS:primary        1
CS.US:primary     2
CS.US_ABC:primary 3
```

Why does it work for "0"?  It works because "0" is not a vector but a character scalar

```
q)type "0"
-10h
q)type "primary"
10h
```

and with a scalar on the right, `,'` works the same as `.\:`:

```
q)"ab",'"0"
"a0"
"b0"
q)"ab",\:"0"
"a0"
"b0"
```

Finally, your query will run faster if you first prepend ":" to the suffix and then append the result to each service:

```
q)update service:`$(string[service],\:":","primary") from tab
service           y
-------------------
CS:primary        1
CS.US:primary     2
CS.US_ABC:primary 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  q)update service:`$(((string[service],'(":"))),'(count[i]#enlist "primary")) 
  from tab
  service           y
  -------------------
  CS:primary        1
  CS.US:primary     2
  CS.US_ABC:primary 3
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.