# Adding a table to HDB by using dbmaint function

Tags: kdb

I would like to backfill a table to all dates in HDB. but the table has like 100 columns. What's the fastest way to backfill with the existing table?
I tried to get the schema from the current table and use the schema to backfill but doesn't work.

this is what I tried:

```
oldTable:0#newTable;
addtable[dbdir;`table;oldTable]
```

but this doesn't work. Any good way?

Comment: I asked [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45194204/472495) whether you could refrain from signing your posts. That still applies here, and this guideline is in the Help Centre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the table exist within the latest date partition of the HDB?

If so .Q.chk will add tables to partitions in which they are missing.

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qchk-fill-hdb

And with regards to addtable, what specific error are you getting when trying the above?

Comment: What is stored within the dbdir variable? I have been testing and can't trigger the nyi error..

Comment: dbdir i used the actualy path `: path

Comment: i think nyi error is from third argument. If i change that it will give me another error.

Comment: That's good that .Q.chk works. Ensure dbdir has no spaces e.g. `:path as that too would cause errors. If you're getting a 'type error when changing the third argument, your error is most likely caused by some enumeration issue.

Comment: hi, just wondering if this works if in one table some dates missed columns? if not, what command would work? Thanks!

Comment: No, in that case use the addcol function from dbmaint.q: https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/utils/dbmaint.md#addcol